# How to execute update and delete query on sql view?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel-5, mariadb

I have created a view which is showing the data from multiple tables . now I want to perform Data manipulation operations on view . How can I achieve this ?

**This is my view**

```
CREATE 
    ALGORITHM = UNDEFINED 
    DEFINER = `forge`@`%` 
    SQL SECURITY DEFINER
VIEW `contact_view` AS
    SELECT 
        `c`.`id` AS `id`,
        `c`.`fname` AS `fname`,
        `c`.`mname` AS `mname`,
        `c`.`lname` AS `lname`,
        CONCAT(`c`.`fname`, ' ', `c`.`lname`) AS `fullname`,
        `c`.`gender` AS `gender`,
        `c`.`dob` AS `dob`,
        `c`.`points` AS `points`,
        `c`.`stars` AS `star`,
        `c`.`inst_id` AS `inst_id`,
        `c`.`ingr_id` AS `ingr_id`,
        `c`.`fami_id` AS `fami_id`,
        `c`.`sour_id` AS `sour_id`,
        `c`.`image` AS `img`,
        `c`.`address` AS `address`,
        `c`.`email` AS `email`,
        `c`.`doc` AS `doc`,
        `cl`.`value` AS `mobile`,
        `p`.`district` AS `district`,
        `p`.`pincode` AS `pincode`
    FROM
        (((`contact` `c`
        JOIN `communication_link` `cl`)
        JOIN `contact_communication` `cc`)
        JOIN `pincode_db` `p`)
    WHERE
        ((`cl`.`cont_id` = `c`.`id`)
            AND (`cl`.`coco_id` = 1)
            AND (`c`.`pinc_id` = `p`.`id`))
```

Comment: is there any other way to achieve this ?

Comment: View is just a `pre-defined SELECT statement`. You can not do any update or delete in views. If you want to achieve data manipulation operations, then try `stored procedure`.

Comment: @E4c5 are you sure about that?

Comment: if you have correctly used foreign keys, deleting from the main table will automatically zap the related rows from other tables.

Comment: nope . I am not using foreign key anywhere.

Comment: Can I use stored procedure to update columns of multiple table which do not have foreign keys?

Comment: why don't you first fix your data by using foreign keys?

Comment: well @Strawberry , you are right, there are some situations where you can insert or update to to multiple table view! you learn something everyday :)

Comment: @e4c5 It's simple. I don't want to use that anyway

Comment: be prepared to handle a hugely complex data cleanup in the near future

Comment: nope, I can handle a hugely complex data easily. There is always one column in each table referring to other table's column exactly the same way foreign key does but there are couple of reason behind not using the foreign key.

Answer (score 2):

In MySQL views can be updatable if they meet certain criteria described in the MySQL documentation on [Updatable and Insertable Views](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/view-updatability.html). Your view seems to be updateable because it does not contain any of the following:

> Aggregate functions (SUM(), MIN(), MAX(), COUNT(), and so forth)
>
> • DISTINCT
>
> • GROUP BY
>
> • HAVING
>
> • UNION or UNION ALL
>
> • Subquery in the select list
>
> Before MySQL 5.7.11, subqueries in the select list fail for INSERT,
>   but are okay for UPDATE, DELETE. As of MySQL 5.7.11, that is still
>   true for nondependent subqueries. For dependent subqueries in the
>   select list, no data change statements are permitted.
>
> • Certain joins (see additional join discussion later in this section)
>
> • Reference to nonupdatable view in the FROM clause
>
> • Subquery in the WHERE clause that refers to a table in the FROM
>   clause
>
> • Refers only to literal values (in this case, there is no underlying
>   table to update)
>
> • ALGORITHM = TEMPTABLE (use of a temporary table always makes a view
>   nonupdatable)
>
> • Multiple references to any column of a base table (fails for INSERT,
>   okay for UPDATE, DELETE)

However, it is probably not insertable because the `fullname` field is calculated by an expression.

To confirm if your view is updateable, use the method described in the above documentation:

> MySQL sets a flag, called the view updatability flag, at CREATE VIEW time. The flag is set to YES (true) if UPDATE and DELETE (and similar operations) are legal for the view. Otherwise, the flag is set to NO (false). The IS_UPDATABLE column in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEWS table displays the status of this flag.

If your view is updateable, then just use it as if it was a table in your delete or update statements:

```
update contact_view set fname='whatever'
```

If your view is not updateable, then you need to write your own update and delete statements to perform the modifications. How you create them will depend on your exact requirements. Particularly for delete operations you may want to consider using foreign keys with `on delete cascade` clause to delete related child records.

Comment: Any reason for accepting the answer and then un-accepting it?